# Django's filter_horizontal - stop enter presses submitting the form

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, if there's something broken about [`filter_horizontal`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal), or if my expectations of the way it should behave are wrong. Any insights appreciated!

In my mind, when you use `filter_horizontal`, type a few characters into the text box to narrow down your choice such that there's a single item, and hit enter, it should:

1. Add the item to the selected list
2. clear your entered text (allowing you to add another).

What it actually does is:

1. Add your item to the selected list
2. Keep the text in the filter box
3. Submit the form, without saving your new selection

Am I doing something wrong? Is this the behaviour everyone sees? Is there a way to work around this?

I'm using Django 1.2.3, and I've tested this in Chrome 8.0.552.237, Firefox 3.6.13, and IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm the behavior on Django 1.2.1.

**Problem:**

It looks like `admin/js/SelectFilter2.js` registers a key up handler to do the filtering. This handler also returns false if the key was the enter key, which tries to cancel the form submit.

From admin/js/SelectFilter2.js line 85 or so:

```
    // don't submit form if user pressed Enter
    if ((event.which && event.which == 13) || (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13)) {
        from.selectedIndex = 0;
        SelectBox.move(field_id + '_from', field_id + '_to');
        from.selectedIndex = 0;
        return false;
    }
```

This seemed fine to me, so I added an event handler at the end of the `init` method to catch the form's submit event:

```
    addEvent(document.forms[0], 'submit', function(event) {
        console.log("Form submitted"); 
    }
```

After doing that, it's clear that submit fires *before* the `keyUp` event. Thus, pressing enter submits the form, and the `keyUp` event never gets to the field.

**Workaround:**

I was able to work around the behavior by discarding all enter `keyUp`'s on the form itself. Add this to the end of the init method in `SelectFilter2.js`:

```
    addEvent(document.forms[0], 'keyup', function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the quick and dirty way to fix the problem, but the form event fires after the field's event, so it seems to work. But it also stops the enter key from submitting the form everywhere else too.

This should probably be filed as a [django bug](http://code.djangoproject.com/simpleticket).

Comment: This didn't work for me, although it appears like it should.  What version of Django did you test this against?